# Error refreshing PFInstallation.currentInstallation()

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios-simulator

I am getting the following error calling PFInstallation.currentInstallation().fetchInBackgroundWithBlock.

> 2015-07-31 07:12:13.944 Heist Buddy[20052:148805] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't
>   refresh an object that hasn't been saved to the server.'

I started getting this error after I reset content and settings in the iOS Simulator.

It seems that the PFInstallation.currentInstallation() is not saving to Parse.com,  when I print currentInstallation I get:

> {
>       deviceType = ios;
>       installationId = "475ee2cb-2513-4e45-a4ae-a3b82c12ee8a"; }

Which seems to be missing a few fields compared to the other installation entries on Parse.com.

I tried saving with PFInstallation.currentInstallation.saveInBackground, but ended up with the same error. I tried looking around for a solution, I manage to find [a post on Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/questions/help-with-pfinstallation-currentinstallation) about the same issue, but it seemed to be unsolved.

I am confused to why PFInstallation has stopped saving. Internet connection is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using saveInBackgroundWithBlock fixed my issue

Comment: Did you check that it actually saved it? For me it doesn't. I had to restart the app so it uploads the PFInstalltion object. But how can I upload a new PFInstallation object after that error was caught?